# crontab repeated schedule with elevated privileges

Tags: linux, cron, root

I need to execute the following command every 15 minutes:

```
    sudo chmod -R 777 /directory
```

I am using Ubuntu server. The instruction must execute with elevated privileges (root).

I was thinking of using the /etc/cron.xxx directory.

Can someone please direct me how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. It would be interesting to understand why you need to do this, because there may be other solutions to fix what I assume is an underlying permissions issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute a command as root every 15 minutes, add the command to root's own crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then, in the crontab, add

```
*/15 * * * * chmod -R 777 /directory
```

Save and exit the editor.

Since cron jobs are running as the user who owns the job, root in this case, `sudo` will not be used in the crontab.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this from root's crontab - not your user's crontab. Actually, you probably *could* do it from your `crontab`, but you would need to work out the mechanics of authentication (i.e. a sudo-enabled userid & password). You could do this through environment variables, but...

```
sudo crontab -e
```

will open root's crontab for editing. You won't need to prefix your command with `sudo` - just enter it as you would if you were `su root`; for example:

```
* * * * * date >> /etc/mydatalog.txt
```

Save & close the editor.

To verify this works, from your user account:

```
sudo tail -f /etc/mydatalog.txt
```

In your case, the `sudo` is not needed from root's crontab, so this should work:

```
chmod -R 777 /directory
```

Comment: Use `date >>/etc/mydatalog.txt` instead of that command substitution with `echo`.

Comment: So my understanding is that since I sudo'ed the crontab anything I type will inherit root functionality

Comment: @chribonn: That is correct, but be careful of making broad assumptions. By that I only mean that, *in general* cron jobs do not "inherit" your (or root's) environment (for example). [This example](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/WhatIsCronEnvironment.md) may explain my comment more clearly.